# Backbone fetch single model attributes

Tags: backbone.js

im trying to fetch a single Models attributes. I use this model as kind of a config file for an app im currently building. But i cant get my head around how to get the attributes in a nice way.

The model looks like this:

```
WelcomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ 

    url: "assets/json/config.json",

    parse: function (response) {
        return response.data;
    }
});
```

The json looks liks this:

```
{   
    "data": [{
        "companyName": "lorem ipsum",
        "companyLogo": "loremipsum.png"
    }]
}
```

And in my view i fetch it like this.

```
this.model = new WelcomeModel();

this.model.fetch({  
    success: function(model,response) {
        console.log(model);
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('error')
    }
});
```

Comment: why your WelcomeModel is instance of Backbone.Collection not Backbone.Model ?

Comment: Sorry, was a misake then i pasted it. I have edited my post.

Comment: add defaults: { companyName: '', companyLogo: ''  } to WelcomeModel

Comment: + you have to return response.data[0] instead response.data

Comment: Thank you! I have to read up a bit on Models. Works now tho.

Comment: glad to help, i'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `parse` method returns array instead object. Replace

```
return response.data
```

with

```
return response.data[0];
```

2) add `defaults` hash to your `WelcomeModel` model.

```
defaults: { 
    companyName: '', 
    companyLogo: '' 
}
```